# Cannot create a SQLite table on an Android Physical Device

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create a table using SQLite on a Sony Xperia phone. It creates the table properly in an emulator however when I try to run it on the physical device the table isn't created. It doesn't appear to show any errors in the Logcat

Here is the output for the Logcat:

```
2019-08-05 13:21:22.788 29935-29935/? I/xample.todolis: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-08-05 13:21:23.014 29935-29935/com.example.todolist I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2019-08-05 13:21:23.245 29935-29935/com.example.todolist W/xample.todolis: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-08-05 13:21:23.247 29935-29935/com.example.todolist W/xample.todolis: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-08-05 13:21:23.319 29935-29935/com.example.todolist D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-08-05 13:21:23.485 29935-29952/com.example.todolist I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 9128d71, Ib33d3e8e13
    Build Date                       : 10/23/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.01
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
2019-08-05 13:21:23.485 29935-29952/com.example.todolist I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
2019-08-05 13:21:23.493 29935-29952/com.example.todolist I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2019-08-05 13:21:23.497 29935-29952/com.example.todolist I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-08-05 13:21:23.497 29935-29952/com.example.todolist I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-08-05 13:21:23.498 29935-29952/com.example.todolist I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-08-05 13:21:23.498 29935-29952/com.example.todolist D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2019-08-05 13:21:27.411 29935-29935/com.example.todolist W/DecorView[]: The visibility of the navigation bar is low, color=ffffffff, hasLightNavBar=true, isFloating=true
2019-08-05 13:21:28.208 29935-29935/com.example.todolist I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 7780 bytes, containing 2 windows, 31 views
2019-08-05 13:21:29.807 29935-29935/com.example.todolist D/db: Add item is clicked
2019-08-05 13:21:29.807 29935-29935/com.example.todolist D/db: add items
2019-08-05 13:21:29.877 29935-29935/com.example.todolist D/db: Creating db first time with table items
2019-08-05 13:21:29.881 29935-29935/com.example.todolist D/db: executed
2019-08-05 13:21:29.910 29935-29952/com.example.todolist D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x75bf47e300 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x75bf678880
```

This is the code for the DatabaseHelper class I created

```
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todo.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "items";

    private static DatabaseHelper instance = null;

    public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Log.d("db","Creating db first time with table " + TABLE_NAME);

        try {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,description TEXT, completed INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)");
            Log.d("db", "executed");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

and this is the code I used to insert my item

```
    public void addItem(ToDoItem item) {

        Log.d("db","add items");

        items.add(item);

        ContentValues newItem = new ContentValues();
        newItem.put("description", item.getDescription());
        newItem.put("completed", item.isComplete());



        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,newItem);
    }
```

I can see the database in the File Explorer for the phone however,
when I open the database in DB Browser for SQLite no table has been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When opening the database you should copy 3 files not just one for use by DB Browser. The database file itself and also the files that are the same name but suffixed with **-wal** and **-shm**.

As unless the database has been checkpointed the **-wal** and **-shm** files will contain the un-checkpointed (uncommitted) data.

- This does assume that WAL ([Write-ahead logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)) is being used, which is the default for Android 9+ devices.

Closing the database would force checkpointing, in which case the -wal and -shm files would be deleted or empty.

Comment: So does this mean my data isn't being committed when I run my code?

Comment: Actually I understand what you are saying now. Thank you so much!